# Ruby Nokogiri Scraping data URL

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Here is what I want is the **id** of eng_tid. so what should i do to get this id code

```
<a data-gt="{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"100016034050254","eng_data":[]}}" href="https://www.facebook.com/thokchom.tombung?fref=pb&amp;hc_location=profile_browser" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100016034050254&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22hc_location%22%3A%22profile_browser%22%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1">Thokchom Tombung</a>

require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'
require 'csv'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("index.html"))

links = page.css('li._5i_q').css("a[data-gt]").children.map {|name| name.text }
puts links

CSV.open('fileId.csv', 'w') do |csv|
   csv << links
end
```

Comment: Can you confirm the value in the `data-gt` attribute? Does it have single quotes or double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these two lines you can get `eng_tid` from `data-hovercard` `id` param:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(Rails.root + "app/views/home/index.html"))

@id = page.css("a").map {|element| element["data-hovercard"][/id=([^&]*)/].gsub('id=', '')}
```

Here is github sample ruby on rails web project which will show you extracted url number on index page: https://github.com/nezirz/nokogiri_stackoverflow_answer

So you need to clone this project to your pc `git clone git@github.com:nezirz/nokogiri_stackoverflow_answer.git` and run inside project folder `bundle install` and finally `rails s` and you will see on web site the requested number, so you can use this code as a sample and manage it to your needs.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 5: from scrape.rb:10:in `<main>'
 4: from scrape.rb:10:in `map'
 3: from /Users/sino/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:203:in `each'
 2: from /Users/sino/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:203:in `upto'
 1: from /Users/sino/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:204:in `block in each'
scrape.rb:11:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: @khdeep can you please download the project pushed to github and try at your pc.

Comment: yeah it's working with your index html but when i put my index html i get error like before

Comment: check path to your index.html

Comment: here is a file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mpb4GBQ1HhCd5W7kCygjIdcUCOzjBqRM/view?usp=sharing